# Unable to get plot.ion() within an if statement to assess progress of model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am having an issue with live plotting. I am running a neural network with tensorflow and want to see progress via a live graph. The code below is what I currently have.

This sets up the plot

```
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot(y_test)
line2, = ax1.plot(y_test*0.5)
plt.show()
```

then this is how I want to check progress

```
if np.mod(i, 5) == 0:
   pred = net.run(out, feed_dict={X: X_test})
   line2.set_ydata(pred)
   plt.pause(0.01)
```

I am currently receiving a blank graph and cannot work out why. Please help.

Comment: What is `i` here?

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(y_test)
ax1.plot(y_test*0.5)
plt.show()

# Presumably there should be a for loop here
for i in range(max_iter):
    # Code to fit the neural net, "net" to latest batch of data
    # ...

    if i % 5 == 0:
       pred = net.run(out, feed_dict={X: X_test})
       ax1.clear()
       ax1.plot(y_test)
       ax1.plot(pred)
       plt.pause(0.01)
```

Comment: This hasn't solved the problem, still getting a blank graph

Comment: Then you should check whether the values in `y_test` and `pred` are valid, and if they are 1 dim arrays. I tried this by setting `pred` and `y_test` to be 1 dimensional arrays of a particular size randomly generated at each iteration and it works. You might also need to increase the time to pause if you are plotting many points.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, will give it a go now